# Parse Server Push Notification to Array of Users

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-server

I am passing "message" of type String and "User" of type `[String]()`

```
Parse.Cloud.define("invite", function(request,response) {

    var message = request.params.message;
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.containedIn("user",request.params.User);  

    Parse.Push.send({
      where: pushQuery,
      data : { 
        alert: message,
        "badge": 1,
      }
    }, {
    success: function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    response.success(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    response.error(error.message)
    },
    useMasterKey: true
    });
});
```

I am getting the following error in the logs when trying to run this code

```
_PushStatus Qwd8rDJKLu: error while sending push code=107, message=bad $in value
```

Comment: Did you check the result of pushQuery?

Comment: What is the value of `request.params.User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second param provided to [`Parse.Query.containedIn`](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/de4bc1c3597ed21a86b542500a84070ce1c9d742/src/ParseQuery.js#L841) must be an `array`. The only way this `bad $in value` error message [can appear](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/960431b92d9d2bb77f2ee082648bd4b140581a67/src/Adapters/Storage/Postgres/PostgresStorageAdapter.js#L418) is when the second param is not `undefined` and not an `array`.

You should make sure the value of `request.params.User` is an actual `array`. You can use `console.log(typeof request.params.User)` to check this.

As you state you are passing the type `[String]()`, it might be converted to an actual string with brackets and all.